# Writing string and integer in SQLite

Tags: database, string, matlab, sqlite

I am new here and general in coding and databases. However I need to write a code to add some data in an existing SQLite Database. I am almost ready with the code, but unfortunately there is a problem I can't fix on my own. I hope you can help me.

I took a SQLite Database to Matlab, added some columns. I filled some lines in the new columns and want to add the new information in my SQLite database. Unlucky for me the new information is not just integer. There are 2 columns with just strings.

```
query= sprintf('UPDATE Kennzahlen SET %s = %f WHERE %s = 
%f',momSpaltenname,momZelleninhalt,Par_DBLaufindex,momZeile);
exec(conn, query);
```

> Kennzahlen=Name of the database momSpaltenname= Name of the current
>   column momZelleninhalt=content of the current cell par_DBLaufindex=
>   name of the column in the database, which shows the number of line
>   momZeile=number of line

It works just fine for integers, but with strings I get the error:

> Error using sqlite/exec Received exception (SQL error or missing
>   database D:\Matlab Skri\DB_Krallmann_CX50_orig.db. (unrecognized
>   token: "67.000000UPDATE")) upon attempting an operation; details:
>   UPDATE Kennzahlen SET Werkzeug_Bezeichnung3 = 116.000000 WHERE est =
>   67.000000UPDATE Kennzahlen SET ycID = 280570.000000 WHERE

English isn't my first language, I hope i could describe my problem well enough. If there are any questions, don't hasitate to ask.
I really hope someone can help me out.

p.s.: I added new columns before that with

```
Spaltennamen=cellstr(char('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h'));
for k = 1:size(Spaltennamen,1)
    momSpaltenname = cell2mat(Spaltennamen(k));
    try
    query = sprintf('ALTER TABLE Kennzahlen ADD %s varchar ', 
    momSpaltenname);
    exec(conn, query);
    catch
    end 
end
```

Comment: It looks like two SQL statements that are intended to be executed sequentially have been concatenated, producing a syntax error.  This might occur because a) your SQL statement does not end with a semicolon, and b) your connection might not be set to autocommit each statement.

Comment: put a semicolon after the %f.  ie- ...%s = %f;' etc.